# Method for validating properties based on passed conditions

Tags: c#, object-oriented, validation, linq-expressions

I wrote a method for validating properties based on passed conditions. It works well, but declaration takes more space than the actual condition. Is there any way to make it shorter?

```
public virtual string Validate(string propertyName, params Tuple<Expression<Func<bool>>, string>[] predicates)
{
    if (!ValidationProperties.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        throw new ArgumentException($"No property found with name '{propertyName}'. Make sure you register it first.");

    foreach (var predicate in predicates)
    {
        if (predicate.Item1.Compile().Invoke())
        {
            ValidationProperties[propertyName] = false;
            ValidationChangedEvent?.Invoke(this, false);
            return predicate.Item2;
        }
    }

    ValidationProperties[propertyName] = true;

    if (ValidationProperties.All(pair => pair.Value))
        ValidationChangedEvent?.Invoke(this, true);

    return null;
}
```

And here's example of call which I want to be shorter:

```
 var result = Validate(nameof(FilePath), 
                        new Tuple<Expression<Func<bool>>, string>(() => string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePath), "Select a file to load"));
```

Basically I want to get rid of: `new Tuple<Expression<Func<bool>>, string>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class encapsulating the two properties suggested by [@eurotrash](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/150806/59161) is definitely a good idea. I think name `ValidationRule` should be ok.

```
class ValidationRule
{
    public ValidationRule(Func<bool> predicate, string message)
    {
        Predicate = predicate;
        Message = message;
    }
    public Func<bool> Predicate { get; }
    public string Message { get; }
}
```

I'd go further and create a collection so that I can use the collection initializer to specify the rules. This means collection class must implement the `IEnumerable<T>` interface and some `Add(..)` method. Then we can use the syntax:

```
new SomeCollection
{
   Item1, Item2
}
```

or if the `Add(..)` requires more then one parameter:

```
new SomeCollection
{
   { Item1, Item1a },
   { Item2, Item2a },
}
```

so our new collection is

```
class ValidationRuleCollection : IEnumerable<ValidationRule>
{
    private readonly List<ValidationRule> _rules = new List<ValidationRule>();

    public ValidationRuleCollection Add(Func<bool> predicate, string message)
    {
        _rules.Add(new ValidationRule(predicate, message));
        return this;
    }

    public IEnumerator<ValidationRule> GetEnumerator() => _rules.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Then you could use it like this

```
var result = Validate(nameof(FilePath), new ValidationRuleCollection
{
    { () => string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePath), "Select a file to load" },
});
```

You don't need the `Expression` for it. You're not using it here. It adds overhead but does not have any advantage in this case.

---

The `foreach` loop can be replaced with LINQ. You stop at the first `true` result so use the `FirstOrDefault` to find it.

```
var rule = validationRules.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Predicate());
if (rule != null)
{
    ValidationProperties[propertyName] = false;
    ValidationChangedEvent?.Invoke(this, false);
    return rule.Message;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Basically I want to get rid of: `new Tuple<Expression<Func<bool>>, string>`

Create your own class instead of the lengthy Tuple?

```
class X // not sure what to call it
{
    public Expression<Func<bool>> Predicate { get; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; }

    public X(Expression<Func<bool>> predicate, string errorMessage)
    {
        Predicate = predicate;
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
}

static string Validate(string propertyName, params X[] predicates)
{
    // ...        
}

var result = Validate(nameof(FilePath),
    new X(() => string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePath), "Select a file to load"));
```

Comment: Exactly what I was doing guess you were faster ^^.